# How to pass string value from React service to Java spring boot controller?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot

I have a service.jsx file with this method:

```
getCustomerRentalsList(id) {
    console.log("getCustomerRentalsList FE service!!" + id);
    console.log("getCustomerRentalsList type on service: " + typeof(id))
    return fetch(RENTAL_API_BASE_URL + "/getCustomerRentalsList", {
        method: 'get',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            'credentials': 'same-origin',
    })
    .then(res => res.json());
```

And a controller on the other end with this method:

```
@GetMapping("/getCustomerRentalsList")
public List<String> getCustomerRentalsList(String id) {
    System.out.println("TEST ID: " + id);
    if(id != null){
        List<String> list = service.getCustomerRentalsList(id);
        return list;
    }
    else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Id value cannot be null!!");
    }
}
```

The test-prints in the React service show that the id-value I want is recieved from my component method.
The test-prints in the backend controller, however, show that the value of id is null.

How do I pass on the parameter? I have a different simple GET-request that works fine, and a couple of POST-requests that also work fine. So I'm positive the problem lies in how to pass the variable. I've had a look around different websites and not found an answer that works.

I'll appreciate good explanations on why this doesn't work, possibly good resources that explain it well (haven't found any myself) as I'm trying to learn.

Comment: youre not passing the 'id' variable anywhere, maybe something like this? `    return fetch(RENTAL_API_BASE_URL + "/getCustomerRentalsList?id=" + id, {`

Comment: @premek.v Thank you, I see now where I have gone wrong and your answer helped me to search for the information I needed so I can read up on fetch() API and requests.